# How to rename the first level keys of struct with PySpark in Azure Databricks?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, field

I would like to rename the keys of the first level objects inside my payload.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *  
ds = {'Fruits': {'apple': {'color': 'red'},'mango': {'color': 'green'}}, 'Vegetables': None}
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([ds]))
df.printSchema()
"""
root
 |-- Fruits: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- apple: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- shape: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mango: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Vegetables: string (nullable = true)
"""
```

Desired output:

```
root
 |-- Fruits: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- APPLE: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- shape: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MANGO: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Vegetables: string (nullable = true)
```

In this case I would like to rename the keys in the first level to uppercase.

If I had a map type I could use transform keys:

```py
df.select(transform_keys("Fruits", lambda k, _: upper(k)).alias("data_upper")).display()
```

Unfortunately, I have a struct type.

> AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'transform_keys(Fruits,
> lambdafunction(upper(x_18), x_18, y_19))' due to argument data type
> mismatch: argument 1 requires map type, however, 'Fruits' is of
> structapple:struct<color:string,shape:string,mango:structcolor:string>
> type.;

I'm using Databricks runtime 10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you tried to use (`transform_keys`) is for *map* type columns. Your column type is *struct*.

You could use `withField`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
ds = spark.createDataFrame([], 'Fruits struct<apple:struct<color:string,shape:string>,mango:struct<color:string>>, Vegetables string')
ds.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- Fruits: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- apple: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- shape: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- mango: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- Vegetables: string (nullable = true)

ds = ds.withColumn('Fruits', F.col('Fruits').withField('APPLE', F.col('Fruits.apple')))
ds = ds.withColumn('Fruits', F.col('Fruits').withField('MANGO', F.col('Fruits.mango')))

ds.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- Fruits: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- APPLE: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- shape: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- MANGO: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- Vegetables: string (nullable = true)
```

You can also recreate the structure, but you will need to include all of the struct fields when recreating.

```py
ds = ds.withColumn('Fruits', F.struct(
    F.col('Fruits.apple').alias('APPLE'),
    F.col('Fruits.mango').alias('MANGO'),
))

ds.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- Fruits: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- APPLE: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- shape: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- MANGO: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- Vegetables: string (nullable = true)
```